# Maximum Power Transfer with complex source impedance

Tags: resistors

I have a question about maximum power transfer involving an AC circuit, where there is a Thevenin circuit with a complex impedance. If it's asking for the load to be purely resistive, how can I know which value to plug in?

Comment: Maybe you will find a hint here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching

Answer (score 1):

I believe for maximum power transfer you want the load to be the complex conjugate of your source impedance: ZL = *Zs

I.E. if your source Z is capacitive you want an inductive load and vice versa.

Comment: Yeah, for the case that the load you are looking for is complex as the impedance, I think I have expressed myself wrong up there. But I am looking for a load that is purely resistive. By load I mean the resistance that is going to be attached to the Vth.

Comment: Ah I see. So I believe the best you could do is pretend the Thevinen is also purely resistive. So RL = Rs. If you put the impedance on the real-imaginary plane, using ZL = R is the closest you can get to *Zs.